# Remove all groups withen a specific OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, data-cleaning

I'm attempting to make an AD cleanup script that will go through a terminated OU and verify all users are removed from specific OU's. currently if I run it it will remove all users in the terminated OU from all OU's. I might just be blind but is there an easy way to have it only remove groups from selected OU's?

```
$OUs = "OU=Terminated,OU=####,OU=####,DC=####,DC=####"

$results = foreach ($OU in $OUs) {
    get-aduser -SearchBase $OU -filter * -properties MemberOf | foreach-object {
        ? $_.MemberOf -like "*OU I want removed*" | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $_.DistinguishedName -Confirm:$false -whatif
    }
}
$results | Export-Csv '.\Users groups have been remoed from.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

I thought it would work, however all it gives me is:

```
Where-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection'.
At C:\###\###\###\accounts script.ps1:8 char:13
+             ? $_.MemberOf -like "*Distrobution Lists*" | <#%{$keep -n ...
```

Comment: are you trying to remove all groups from users that are in Terminated OU (and sub OUs) ?

Comment: All the users i am modifying are in the terminated OU, but all the groups are located in another separate OU

Comment: MemberOf is a collection so you need to loop over that directly.  At that point you can filter it if needed then do the remove.  Be warned that if you nest a second foreach you won't be able to refer to the user with $_.DistinguishedName.  You'd need to refactor a bit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you have a separate OU for groups, you can iterate over the groups that a terminated user has and see if any of the groups belong to that specific OU. If thats the case, then remove all those groups.

```
$results = ""

foreach ($ou in $OUs) 
{
  $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter * 
  foreach ($user in $users)
  {
      $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $User | ? {$_.distinguishedName -like "*OU I WANT TO REMOVE FROM*" }
      foreach($group in $groups) 
      {
         Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $user -MemberOf $group -whatif
         results += "$user removed from its Groups: $($groups | % { $_.name })\r\n"          
      }
  }
}

results | Out-File -Append C:\temp\new.txt
```

$groups will have members in this format. You can use distinguishedName as a filter type and use something like "OU=Groups,DC=this,DC=com" instead of "OU=Groups" that might be considered broad.

```
distinguishedName : CN=GroupName,OU=****,DC=****,DC=****
GroupCategory     : Security
GroupScope        : Global
name              : <Name Of The Group>
objectClass       : group
objectGUID        : <Object Guid>
SamAccountName    : <Name Of The Group>
SID               : <SID>
```

I like to keep the variables so i can use them to log what changes are being performed.

**NOTE:** I used `-whatif` to make sure it doesnt do what you intend to for testing reasons. `Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` also updates user with one group.

**Another Way to go about it**

```
foreach ($ou in $OUs) 
{
  $users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase $ou -Filter * 
  $groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase $DecomOUGROUP
  foreach($group in $groups) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $users -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  }
}
```